# java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while staging packages

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I am facing RuntimeException when running dataflow (Apache Beam SDK 2.4.0) from AppEngine Cron jobs.

I tried to investigate on dependencies but It leads me nowhere.
Does anyone have a clue why this error occurs?

This problem did not happen to me with an older version of Dataflow (like 1.9.1 for example)

Below the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while staging packages
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElements(PackageUtil.java:396)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElements(PackageUtil.java:273)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.GcsStager.stageFiles(GcsStager.java:76)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.GcsStager.stageDefaultFiles(GcsStager.java:64)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:661)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:174)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:311)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:297)
at com.apps.loader.dataflow.ContactExtenderDataflow.runDataflow(ContactActualExtenderDataflow.java:80)
at com.apps.loader.dataflow.ContactExtenderDataflow.runDataflow(ContactActualExtenderDataflow.java:74)
at com.apps.loader.servlet.ContactExtenderLoader.doGetPost(ContactActualExtenderLoader.java:51)
at com.apps.loader.servlet.ContactExtenderLoader.doPost(ContactActualExtenderLoader.java:41)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:297)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:202)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:81)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:108)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:686)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:648)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:618)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:812)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:274)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Operation not allowed in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$CurrentRequestThreadFactory.newThread(ApiProxyImpl.java:1224)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:612)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:925)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1357)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$ListeningDecorator.execute(MoreExecutors.java:530)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.asyncRunStage(CompletableFuture.java:1640)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.runAsync(CompletableFuture.java:1858)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MoreFutures.supplyAsync(MoreFutures.java:98)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stagePackage(PackageUtil.java:173)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.lambda$stageClasspathElements$2(PackageUtil.java:358)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:952)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:926)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty self-explanatory:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Operation not allowed in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
```

On GAE, [new threads must be created by ThreadManager.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime#threads)

Evidently, Apache Beam was compliant with this restriction for your use case, but is no longer.

It may be time to think about moving away from GAE (or Apache Beam).